# I want to use command "bin/nutch inject" to inject my crawling URLs

Tags: nutch

I want to use command `bin/nutch inject` to inject my crawling URLs but I get an error

```
'nutch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Where do I enter this command? I am presently typing this command on the path `C:\Users\Gaurav Kandpal\Desktop\elastic\apache-nutch-2.3-src\apache-nutch-2.3\runtime\local\b` on command prompt.

Comment: Please show us some codes

Answer (score 3):

> Follow steps to install `nutch` in windows **:**

```
1) download and install cygwin from : https://www.cygwin.com/
2) download nutch from : http://nutch.apache.org/downloads.html
3) paste nutch downloaded and extracted file into C:\cygwin64\home\
4) open cygwin terminal and type given commands 

 - $ cd C:
 - $ cd cigwin64
 - $ cd home
 - $ cd apache-nutch
 - $ cd src/bin
 - $ ./nutch
```

> you will get given output **:**

```
Usage: nutch COMMAND
where COMMAND is one of:
 inject         inject new urls into the database
 hostinject     creates or updates an existing host table from a text file
 generate       generate new batches to fetch from crawl db
 fetch          fetch URLs marked during generate
 parse          parse URLs marked during fetch
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please check did you compile the Nutch source code. Then, you should try to run from here /path/to/nutch/runtime/deploy/bin as well in the case you deploy Nutch on a cluster.